# How to read XML header data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

How can I read the data within a root of an XML file in Python 3?

I've done this before where the data is stored between the root and end of header section of an XML file.

Without giving NDA information, here's what I'm trying to parse:

```
  <!--TouchXPRT Workload Result Data-->
     <TouchXPRTResultData Date="..., ..." Version="x">
        <WorkLoad Name="Beautify Photos" Duration="..." DurationUnits="seconds" Rate="..." RateUnits="photos/sec" SourceInfo="Source: x Photos, x Mega Pixels" Iteration="1" />
     </TouchXPRTResultData>
```

What I'm trying to access here is 'Duration: ...'. Only need the value that would be in-place of the '...'. Where previous benchmark XML files store the data between headers:

```
   <PCMark10Score>...</PCMark10Score>
```

This is easy to call to. But TouchXprt decides to store the data I want to access inside the header itself.

Any input on this would be nice! I've tried looking online and the depths of stack overflow for this answer but it seems to be non-existent.

Comment: PCMark10Score is an element while Duration is an attribute of Workload element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @LMC for explaining this.

Previous benchmarks put the data between elements, while TouchXprt puts the data inside of an attribute inside the element.

Using xml.etree.cElementTree, you can access the element's attribute by using ' the .attrib ' tag.

So here's the solution for my situation:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree

    for neighbor in root.iter('WorkLoad'):
        workloads = neighbor.attrib
        workload_to_list = list(workloads)[1]
        workload_values = list(workloads.values())[1]
        print(workload_to_list)
        print(workload_values)
```

Here, I loop through the benchmark XML results and set workloads variable to hold the data. 'neighbor.attrib' will hold a dictionary of the elements where each attribute is separated by a comma. To get the data within the attribute, you may use the ' .value ' tag.

To make things easier, I converted the dictionary to a list to more easily index into it, and there you have it.